I am having error "dial tcp: lookup docker on 1.1.1.1:53: no such host"
I'm having error "error during connect: Post "http://docker:2375/v1.45/volumes/create": dial tcp: lookup docker on 1.1.1.1:53: no such host" when trying to run docker inside a docker:lastest image.
Which can be the problem?
Output:
# Generated by Docker Engine.
# This file can be edited; Docker Engine will not make further changes once it
# has been modified.

nameserver 172.25.8.1
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.1.1.1

# Based on host file: '/etc/resolv.conf' (legacy)
# Overrides: []
...creating volumes: marquez_data, marquez_db-conf, marquez_db-init, marquez_db-backup
error during connect: Post "http://docker:2375/v1.45/volumes/create": dial tcp: lookup docker on 1.1.1.1:53: no such host
error during connect: Post "http://docker:2375/v1.45/volumes/create": dial tcp: lookup docker on 1.1.1.1:53: no such host
error during connect: Post "http://docker:2375/v1.45/volumes/create": dial tcp: lookup docker on 1.1.1.1:53: no such host
error during connect: Post "http://docker:2375/v1.45/volumes/create": dial tcp: lookup docker on 1.1.1.1:53: no such host

Docker file:
# Use a Linux imgage
FROM docker:latest

# Install Docker
RUN apk update

# Install bash
RUN apk add bash

# Install git
RUN apk add --update git

# Clone the Marquez repository
WORKDIR /app
RUN git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/MarquezProject/marquez.git

# Execute the startup script to launch Marquez
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "cat /etc/resolv.conf && cd marquez && ./docker/up.sh"]

# Expose Marquez's web UI port (optional, adjust based on use case)
EXPOSE 3000

